# Alternatives to using Windows Workflow Foundation for workflows in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, workflow-foundation

I've been very unhappy with the consistency and functionality of WF in Sharepoint 2007. Is there an alternative? I could roll my own WF engine if I had to but I imagine there are alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the out of the box work flow functionality with WSS3 or MOSS 2007?

Anyway possible alternatives are

- Create your own with SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio
- Upgrade to SharePoint 2010 which has more workflow options
- 3rd party tool eg Nintex is one.